# Android Mobile-to-Mobile socket connection over public wifi?

Tags: android, sockets

I've written an Android app that includes creating a socket connection between 2 mobiles over wifi. The connection works fine at home with my wireless router and WEP security. However, when I tried to run the app at my local coffee shop, I could not make the socket connection. Both droids were connected to the shop's wireless network and the client was using the correct IP address. However, when I tried to make the connection, I received a SocketTimeoutException. I've tried this app at other (home-type with WEP) locations and as long as both mobiles are connected to the wifi network they can set up the socket connection.

Is there something in the configuration of public wifi networks that doesn't allow socket connections to be set up?

Answer (score 1):

It can be that router in this coffe shop allows only specific ports like 80 for http and other ports are blocked by device, maybe you can try setting up your server on the device on such normally open port.

Comment: I tried setting the port to 80, but it still doesn't work. Actually, using port 80 doesn't even work on my home network.

Comment: what kind of error do you get trying to run on port 80 socket timeout also?

Comment: I get a "Connection refused" message

Comment: What about starting your server application on port 80 is it starting or is it closing? Are you sure you have running server application on port 80 maybe something on android already uses this port so you can try port 21 for ftp or such, look up some port table and try several other ports.